# How to Assign datastorage Limit to the datastore from LM?

Tags: storage, vmware-esx, hard-drive

We have a Data Storeage XYZ with 1TB HDD and 32 GB ram. - We want to assign this to 2 different groups 500GB HDD, 16GB RAM to Group - A and 500GB HDD and 16GB RAM to another group.

We want to set this limit from LM, can you please comments if this is possible? and if yes could you please point us where can we do this in LM?

Answer (score -1):

Regarding storage why limit yourself when you don't need to, just create one big datastore then carve it by VM/.vmdk - that way any spare is spare for either group.

Then just create two resource pools in VC, one for each group, add each group's VMs to each RP - stand back and watch performance and if there's memory (or CPU) contention then you can introduce limits or shares as required.